# text value of xml node into java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

**How do I get JAXB to generate a java class that will allow me access to the textual component of an xml node that contains both text and elements?**

Here is an example of the `xml`:

```
<SomeClass someAttr="avalue">Text goes here.</SomeClass>
```

After `unmarshalling` the above `xml`, I would like to be able to call a java method to return `Text value goes here.`.

The `xsd` is as follows, note that it uses `mixed=true`:

```
<xs:complexType name="Some.Class" mixed="true">
  <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="someclass" type="Some.Class"/>
    <xs:element name="sub" type="Another.Class"/> 
  </xs:choice>
  <xs:attribute name="someAttr" type="xs:NMTOKENS"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

This xsd is causing JAXB to generate the following java, but I do not see the method for getting the text:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Some.Class", propOrder = {"content"})
@Entity(name = "SomeClass")
@Table(name = "SOME_CLASS")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class SomeClass implements Equals, HashCode {

    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "sub", namespace = "urn:some:namespace", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "someclass", namespace = "urn:some:namespace", type = JAXBElement.class)
    })
    @XmlMixed
    protected List<Object> content;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected List<String> someAttr;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Hjid")
    protected Long hjid;
    protected transient List<SomeClass.SomeClassContentItem> contentItems;
    protected transient List<SomeClass.SomeClassSomeAttrItem> someAttrItems;

    @Transient
    public List<Object> getContent() {
        if (content == null) {content = new ArrayList<Object>();}
        return this.content;
    }

    public void setContent(List<Object> content) {this.content = content;}

    @Transient
    public boolean isSetContent() {return ((this.content!= null)&&(!this.content.isEmpty()));}

    public void unsetContent() {this.content = null;}

    @Transient
    public List<String> getSomeAttr() {
        if (someAttr == null) {someAttr = new ArrayList<String>();}
        return this.someAttr;
    }

    public void setSomeAttr(List<String> someAttr) {this.someAttr = someAttr;}

    @Transient
    public boolean isSetSomeAttr() {
        return ((this.someAttr!= null)&&(!this.someAttr.isEmpty()));
    }

    public void unsetSomeAttr() {this.someAttr = null;}

    @Id
    @Column(name = "HJID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getHjid() {return hjid;}

    public void setHjid(Long value) {this.hjid = value;}

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = SomeClass.SomeClassContentItem.class, cascade = {
        CascadeType.ALL
    }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CONTENT_ITEMS_SOME_CLASS_HJID")
    public List<SomeClass.SomeClassContentItem> getContentItems() {
        if (this.contentItems == null) {
            this.contentItems = new ArrayList<SomeClass.SomeClassContentItem>();
        }
        if (MixedItemUtils.shouldBeWrapped(this.content)) {
            this.content = MixedItemUtils.wrap(this.content, this.contentItems, SomeClass.SomeClassContentItem.class);
        }
        return this.contentItems;
    }

    public void setContentItems(List<SomeClass.SomeClassContentItem> value) {
        this.content = null;
        this.contentItems = null;
        this.contentItems = value;
        if (this.contentItems == null) {
            this.contentItems = new ArrayList<SomeClass.SomeClassContentItem>();
        }
        if (MixedItemUtils.shouldBeWrapped(this.content)) {
            this.content = MixedItemUtils.wrap(this.content, this.contentItems, SomeClass.SomeClassContentItem.class);
        }
    }

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = SomeClass.SomeClassSomeAttrItem.class, cascade = {
        CascadeType.ALL
    }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SOME_ATTR_ITEMS_SOME_CLASS_H_0")
    public List<SomeClass.SomeClassSomeAttrItem> getSomeAttrItems() {
        if (this.someAttrItems == null) {
            this.someAttrItems = new ArrayList<SomeClass.SomeClassSomeAttrItem>();
        }
        if (ItemUtils.shouldBeWrapped(this.someAttr)) {
            this.someAttr = ItemUtils.wrap(this.someAttr, this.someAttrItems, SomeClass.SomeClassSomeAttrItem.class);
        }
        return this.someAttrItems;
    }

    public void setSomeAttrItems(List<SomeClass.SomeClassSomeAttrItem> value) {
        this.someAttr = null;
        this.someAttrItems = null;
        this.someAttrItems = value;
        if (this.someAttrItems == null) {
            this.someAttrItems = new ArrayList<SomeClass.SomeClassSomeAttrItem>();
        }
        if (ItemUtils.shouldBeWrapped(this.someAttr)) {
            this.someAttr = ItemUtils.wrap(this.someAttr, this.someAttrItems, SomeClass.SomeClassSomeAttrItem.class);
        }
    }

    public boolean equals(ObjectLocator thisLocator, ObjectLocator thatLocator, Object object, EqualsStrategy strategy) {
        if (!(object instanceof SomeClass)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this == object) {
            return true;
        }
        final SomeClass that = ((SomeClass) object);
        {
            List<Object> lhsContent;
            lhsContent = (this.isSetContent()?this.getContent():null);
            List<Object> rhsContent;
            rhsContent = (that.isSetContent()?that.getContent():null);
            if (!strategy.equals(LocatorUtils.property(thisLocator, "content", lhsContent), LocatorUtils.property(thatLocator, "content", rhsContent), lhsContent, rhsContent)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        {
            List<String> lhsSomeAttr;
            lhsSomeAttr = (this.isSetSomeAttr()?this.getSomeAttr():null);
            List<String> rhsSomeAttr;
            rhsSomeAttr = (that.isSetSomeAttr()?that.getSomeAttr():null);
            if (!strategy.equals(LocatorUtils.property(thisLocator, "someAttr", lhsSomeAttr), LocatorUtils.property(thatLocator, "someAttr", rhsSomeAttr), lhsSomeAttr, rhsSomeAttr)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        final EqualsStrategy strategy = JAXBEqualsStrategy.INSTANCE;
        return equals(null, null, object, strategy);
    }

    public int hashCode(ObjectLocator locator, HashCodeStrategy strategy) {
        int currentHashCode = 1;
        {
            List<Object> theContent;
            theContent = (this.isSetContent()?this.getContent():null);
            currentHashCode = strategy.hashCode(LocatorUtils.property(locator, "content", theContent), currentHashCode, theContent);
        }
        {
            List<String> theSomeAttr;
            theSomeAttr = (this.isSetSomeAttr()?this.getSomeAttr():null);
            currentHashCode = strategy.hashCode(LocatorUtils.property(locator, "someAttr", theSomeAttr), currentHashCode, theSomeAttr);
        }
        return currentHashCode;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        final HashCodeStrategy strategy = JAXBHashCodeStrategy.INSTANCE;
        return this.hashCode(null, strategy);
    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @Entity(name = "SomeClass$SomeClassContentItem")
    @Table(name = "SOME_CLASS_CONTENT_ITEM")
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
    public static class SomeClassContentItem implements MixedItem<JAXBElement<?>> {

        @XmlElementRefs({
            @XmlElementRef(name = "someclass", namespace = "urn:some:namespace", type = JAXBElement.class),
            @XmlElementRef(name = "sub", namespace = "urn:some:namespace", type = JAXBElement.class)
        })
        protected JAXBElement<?> item;
        @XmlAttribute(name = "Text")
        protected String text;
        @XmlAttribute(name = "Hjid")
        protected Long hjid;

        @Transient
        public JAXBElement<?> getItem() {return item;}

        public void setItem(JAXBElement<?> value) {this.item = ((JAXBElement<?> ) value);}

        @Basic
        @Column(name = "TEXT")
        @Lob
        public String getText() {return text;}

        public void setText(String value) {this.text = value;}

        @Id
        @Column(name = "HJID")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        public Long getHjid() {return hjid;}

        public void setHjid(Long value) {this.hjid = value;}

        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = SomeClass.class, cascade = {
            CascadeType.ALL
        }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_SOMECLASS_SOME_CLASS_CO_0")
        public SomeClass getItemSomeclass() {
            if (XmlAdapterUtils.isJAXBElement(SomeClass.class, new QName("urn:some:namespace", "someclass"), SomeClass.class, this.getItem())) {
                return XmlAdapterUtils.unmarshallJAXBElement(((JAXBElement<? extends SomeClass> ) this.getItem()));
            } else {return null;}
        }

        public void setItemSomeclass(SomeClass target) {
            if (target!= null) {
                setItem(XmlAdapterUtils.marshallJAXBElement(SomeClass.class, new QName("urn:some:namespace", "someclass"), SomeClass.class, target));
            }
        }

        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = AnotherClass.class, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_SUB_SOME_CLASS_CONTENT__0")
        public AnotherClass getItemSub() {
            if (XmlAdapterUtils.isJAXBElement(AnotherClass.class, new QName("urn:some:namespace", "sub"), SomeClass.class, this.getItem())) {
                return XmlAdapterUtils.unmarshallJAXBElement(((JAXBElement<? extends AnotherClass> ) this.getItem()));
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public void setItemSub(AnotherClass target) {
            if (target!= null) {
                setItem(XmlAdapterUtils.marshallJAXBElement(AnotherClass.class, new QName("urn:some:namespace", "sub"), SomeClass.class, target));
            }
        }

    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @Entity(name = "SomeClass$SomeClassSomeAttrItem")
    @Table(name = "SOME_CLASS_SOME_ATTR_ITEM")
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
    public static class SomeClassSomeAttrItem implements Item<String> {

        @XmlElement(name = "SomeAttr")
        @XmlSchemaType(name = "NMTOKENS")
        protected String item;
        @XmlAttribute(name = "Hjid")
        protected Long hjid;

        @Basic
        @Column(name = "ITEM")
        public String getItem() {return item;}

        public void setItem(String value) {this.item = value;}

        @Id
        @Column(name = "HJID")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        public Long getHjid() {return hjid;}

        public void setHjid(Long value) {this.hjid = value;}

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This xsd is causing JAXB to generate the following java, but I do not
>   see the method for getting the text:

The `content` property, is the property that can contain the text:

```
@XmlElementRefs({
    @XmlElementRef(name = "sub", namespace = "urn:some:namespace", type = JAXBElement.class),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "someclass", namespace = "urn:some:namespace", type = JAXBElement.class)
})
@XmlMixed
protected List<Object> content;
```

The reason is that since the `Some.Class` type is mixed you can have content like so it all goes in a `List`:

```
<...>
    a
    <someclass/>
    b
    <sub/>
    c
    <sub/>
    d
</...>
```

Comment: Thank you.  The problem may have been that my schema uses the word `content` as a defined attribute name, which would override what you are talking about.  Let me noodle with my code and then get back to you soon.

Comment: I am looking at this in eclipse.  I see the list of objects in the content property.  But what java syntax do I use to extract the text value from the content property?

Comment: In the `List` you will have values that are instances of `JAXBElement` and `String`.  The `String` instances are your text values.