# JAXB Annotation - Attribute hold List/String as a value

Tags: jaxb

I have the following structure

```
  public static class Param implements Serializable
  {

        @XmlValue
        protected Object value;

        @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
        protected String name;
   }
```

Here the attribute "Value" of type "Object" sometime will hold String and sometimes will hold a List so when the value passes is a string the Marshall and unMarshall works fine but when the value is a list the marshall fails, Could you please advise me what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I would make the field/property a `List<String>`, then your `String` is simply a `List` of size 1.

```java
   @XmlValue
   protected List<String> value;
```

---

### UPDATE

> Actually the List may be a List of any object not only a list od
>   String for example List

Then you are going to need to do something like the following:

```java
   @XmlMixed
   protected List<Object> value;
```

See the following related question for some additional information:

- [text value of xml node into java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27002826/text-value-of-xml-node-into-java)

Comment: Thanks Blaise :) , Is there any other solution(an annotation for example ) as by this solution i will need to re-factor all the old code as it expected the value is a string, and a new added feature will require to have a list as a value of a parameter?

Comment: @user2490510 - You can have the field be `List<String>` and then you can have whatever accessors you want.  What are you expecting the XML to look like in both cases?

Comment: Actually the List may be a List of any object not only a list od String for example List<Persons>

Comment: @user2490510 - I have updated my answer to address this point.

Comment: Thanks Blaise so much for your support, will try the last option :) :)

Comment: after trying it i got the following exception :class org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag